# Flutter: Live TV channel steaming problem

Tags: flutter, streaming, channel, television

I want streaming a Live TV channel. That's why I used `flutter_vlc_player 3.0.3`.
When I click the button to starting live TV channel, sometimes it takes a long time to open and sometimes doesn't open.

But When I click the button to starting live TV channel and then pressed "R" for Hot reload in terminal, at this time it opens quickly.

> Here is my source code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_vlc_player/flutter_vlc_player.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _streamUrl;
  VlcPlayerController _vlcViewController;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _vlcViewController = new VlcPlayerController();
  }

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      if (_streamUrl != null) {
        _streamUrl = null;
      } else {
        _streamUrl =
            "http://tempe.appv.jagobd.com:1934/c5V6mmMyX7RpbEU9Mi8xNy8yMDEOGIDU6RgzQ6NTAgdEoaeFzbF92YWxIZTO0U0ezN1IzMyfvcGVMZEJCTEFWeVN3PTOmdFsaWRtaW51aiPhnPTI/atnws-sg.stream/playlist.m3u8";
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _streamUrl == null
                ? Container(
                    child: Center(
                      child: RichText(
                        text: TextSpan(children: [
                          TextSpan(
                            text: 'Stream Closed',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                background: Paint()..color = Colors.red),
                          )
                        ]),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                : Container(
                    child: new VlcPlayer(
                      url: _streamUrl,
                      controller: _vlcViewController,
                      placeholder: Container(),
                      aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    ),
                  )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        child: Icon(_streamUrl == null ? Icons.play_arrow : Icons.pause),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Why does it behave like this and How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think it seems you need `setState` and you should initialize it inside a function like this:

```
_vControllerInit() async {
    final response = await Dio().post(
        "http://jsonplaceholder/api/v1/android-tv/movies",);

    final data = MoviePlayerModel.fromJson(response.data);
    _vController = VlcPlayerController.network(data.data!.file!);
    setState(() {});
  }
```